# How to avoid bug in numpy.place while calculating inverse cumulative distribution function of large numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have probably come across a bug in scipy or numpy, anyone has seen the following issue or has a good workaround?

```
from scipy.stats import distributions
import numpy as np
distributions.norm.ppf(np.ones((30000, 10000)) / 2.0)
```

Results in

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       ..., 
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Smaller runs (like 20000 rows) work fine.

Using numpy 1.10.4.

**EDIT**

Problems seems to be deeper, appearing inside numpy:

```
na = np.zeros((30000, 10000)) * np.nan
np.place(na, np.ones((30000, 10000)), np.ravel(np.ones((30000, 10000))))
```

Resulting in

```
array([[  1.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [  1.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [  1.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       ..., 
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Added bug report: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7207

Comment: I just ran the second code to see if the issue also affected my machine, and it crashed :P  Then I realised that it was creating 900 million 64 bit numbers, and I only have a 4GB machine

Comment: Sorry about that ;-)

Comment: It's indeed likely somewhere in numpy, and not the actual routine itself. `norm.ppf` is outsourced to `special.ndtri` as far as I can tell. If you run `special.ndtri(a)`, you'll find the result is fine. So it's the back and forth between the two routines (involving numpy and ufuncs) that's causing the error.

Comment: Interesting - I get a segfault if I use a boolean mask rather than float64, i.e. `np.place(na, np.ones((30000, 10000), np.bool), np.ravel(np.ones((30000, 10000))))`

Comment: It looks like integer overflow, probably happening somewhere in [`arr_insert_loop`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9ce9b9a7244f4d583e9bc6bc798f642226e6c4b6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c#L313-L352). `np.log2(~np.isnan(na)) == 28.0`, so only the first 2**28 elements in `na` are being filled. I'm also getting random segfaults when the mask is float64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be integer overflow happening within the [`arr_insert_loop`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9ce9b9a7244f4d583e9bc6bc798f642226e6c4b6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c#L313-L352) function in `numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c`. I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/7208) that should fix the issue.